# jQuery File Upload doesn't work in IE9 when compressed with Requirejs

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, jquery-file-upload

My code uses Backbone with Requirejs and [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and  works perfectly in IE 9 when I access the development code directly (without building). As soon as I build it something goes wrong and the request is sent empty to the server.

The only difference I see in the request (using Network capturing in IE9) is that the one that works when I click in the upload button, the Initiator is `click`, and for the one that fails, the initiator is `JS Library XMLHttpRequest`.

So there must be something making the event change when the code gets compressed, but I have no idea how to get closer to the root of the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you requiring the [iFrame Transport plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js)?

I am using jQuery File Upload with Requirejs, and have not seen this issue. Without seeing some code, it is hard to say what is tripping up your application. I suggest updating your question with some relevant code. In the meantime, here is what is working for me.

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    appDir: '../',
    baseUrl: 'js/',
    paths: {
        underscore: '../vendor/lodash.underscore',
        backbone: '../vendor/backbone',
        'jquery.fileupload': '../vendor/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload',
        'jquery.iframe-transport': '../vendor/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport',
        'jquery.ui.widget': '../vendor/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.ui.widget'
    },
    shim: {
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});
```

And in the page that houses the upload control:

**UploadPage.js**

```
define([
    'views/Base',
    'jquery.iframe-transport',
    'jquery.fileupload'
], function(BaseView) {
    return BaseView.extend({
        // Do cool stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: As I said the code works fine when it isn't compressed: all libraries successfully loaded. There must be something in Requirejs's compression that breaks it, but I'm having a hard time finding it. Code validates through JSHint.

Comment: Actually, I was loading it from `shim`, but they are AMD compatible, so your way of loading is the correct and fixed the issue!

Comment: yup this was exactly our problem too, we were loading it as a dependency of fileupload.js, but once we stopped doing that and follow the method above to load it in the view.js file of the backbone app, everything worked great. THANKS BART!

Comment: Same problem here! The solution of loading it in the view worked! THANKS A LOT GUYS!!!